# VB.net Saving an MetaFile / EMF as a bitmap ( .tiff)

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, save, metafile

Currently I have a third party control that generates a Metafile. I can save the .wmf file to disk with out issue.  The problem is how do I render the Metafile as a Tiff file.

Currently I have the following code to get my metafile and save it.

```
 Dim mf As Metafile = page.GetImage(TXTextControl.Page.PageContent.All)



                        Dim enhMetafileHandle As IntPtr = mf.GetHenhmetafile()

                        Dim h As IntPtr
                        Dim bufferSize As UInteger = GetEnhMetaFileBits(enhMetafileHandle, 0, h)
                        Dim buffer(CInt(bufferSize)) As Byte

                        GetEnhMetaFileBits(enhMetafileHandle, bufferSize, buffer)

                        Dim msMetafileStream As New MemoryStream
                        msMetafileStream.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(bufferSize))


                        Dim baMetafileData() As Byte
                        baMetafileData = msMetafileStream.ToArray
                        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mf)


                        mf.Dispose()



                        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\a.wmf", baMetafileData)
```

end sub

_
        Public Shared Function GetEnhMetaFileBits( ByVal hEMF As System.IntPtr, ByVal nSize As UInteger, ByVal lpData As IntPtr) As UInteger
    End Function

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetEnhMetaFileBits")> _

Public Shared Function GetEnhMetaFileBits(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()> ByVal hEMF As System.IntPtr, ByVal nSize As UInteger, ByVal lpData() As Byte) As UInteger
End Function
```

I've tried all sort of IMAGE and Graphic calls and just can't save the meta file as a .tiff. Any suggestions would be great.  I even tried to create a new bitmap and draw the metafile onto it.  I always end up with a GDI exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final Code Looks like:

```
 Dim NewGraphic As Graphics = Nothing
        Dim BitonalImage As Bitmap = Nothing

        Using bmp As New Bitmap(3264, 4224)
            Try

                NewGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                NewGraphic.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, 3264, 4224)
                NewGraphic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                NewGraphic.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                NewGraphic.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit

                NewGraphic.DrawImage(MetaFileToConvert, 0, 0, 3264, 4224)

                BitonalImage = CType(ConvertToBitonal(CType(bmp, Bitmap)), Bitmap)
                BitonalImage.SetResolution(385, 385)

                OutBMP = BitonalImage

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                NewGraphic.Dispose()
                BitonalImage.Dispose()
            End Try

        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard to decipher.  Simply drawing the metafile to a bitmap should get the job done.  For example:

```
Dim mf As Metafile = page.GetImage(TXTextControl.Page.PageContent.All)
Using bmp As New Bitmap(mf.Width, mf.Height)
  Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    gr.DrawImage(mf, 0, 0)
  End Using
  bmp.Save("c:\temp\test.tiff", ImageFormat.Tiff)
End Using
```

Comment: This worked I just messed with the DPI to get my .tiff to be of high quality.

Comment: A metafile is scalable.  Make the bitmap as big as you want it, use the DrawImage overload that takes a Rectangle.